# global.asa doesn't work on IIS 6

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

I copy a few web sites from IIS 5  to IIS 6. I declare an app pool for those sites, I copy also the global.asa file to the root folder but the IIS ignore the global.asa functions.

Any idea?

Comment: Was my answer of any use for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you put a simple .asp page in the virtual folder, does that run? If not it could be that you need to turn on the IIS settings to be able to run classic ASP.

Follow these steps described in: http://www.simongibson.com/intranet/iis6/.

Comment: Hi, Thank for you replay , Yes, simple .asp page run on the server . The OS is win2003 server and there is no "turn on windows features " attribute on the control panel". any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

In IIS6 on win2003 you need to check the Application extension mappings for your website.

Open the **Properties** from the websites context menu, navigate to the **Home Directory Tab**, click **Configuration...** and in the list of Application extensions check that a mapping for the extension .asa exists.

If the mapping exists it should have the following (default) configuration values:

```
Executable: C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll
Extension: .asa
Verbs: Limit to GET,HEAD,POST,TRACE
Script engine: checked
Verify that file exists: checked
```

Since you stated that normal .asp pages are executed without problems the script engine itself should be installed correctly on your machine.